# How to recover deleted records from a geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

A coworker of mine made a copy of a personal geodatabase feature class, and deleted a subset of records from the attribute table.  He was not aware that the original database was still linked to his copy, and therefore he deleted records from the original database.  Is there any way to recover these records?

Comment: So, he made a copy of a personal geodatabase from you ? Can you just give him your original copy ?

Comment: No, the original copy is on our shared server.  We run GIS on Citrix.

Comment: So are you saying he was using SDE or personal geodatabase ? I have both on PC and Citrix.

Comment: The file he copied was a Personal Geodatabase Feature Class.  I am not familiar with SDE.

Comment: In my opinion, should always have make a backup of his work. We have SDE here and I always export it to shapefiles and keep the original ones.

Comment: *Shapefiles* are an inadequate backup medium for geodata archiving form enterprise geodatabases. They corrupt most of the few datatypes they support. Use file geodatabase to prevent data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to recover deleted records in file and personal geodatabases (short of filesystem backup restoration). If you have an enterprise database, you can use the backup and recovery capabilities of your database software (SQL Server, Oracle,...) to recover records.

Comment: There isn't any such thing as "sde format".  ArcSDE is an access protocol, not a storage format.

Comment: "Enterprise geodatabase" is the type. "SDE" dissappeared at the release of 8.0.